IntelliJ Java Konfiguration without access to Environment Variables
Executing the command java -version in a terminal outside of IntelliJ works on my device, but not on the terminal inside the IDE.
I get the error that 'java' is not recognized as name of an cmdlet, function, etc.
Probably my java inside the IDE is not cofigured correctly, but I don't know how to do it right. On top of that I am working on a company Laptop which doesn't give me access to my Environment Variables.
Can anybody  tell me how to solve my konfiguration problem?
I controlled my project SDK etc. but they all seem to be configured correctly.

AFAIK, you can't really restrict access to env variables (at least on Windows). If java is on the PATH and you can use it in the system terminal, then it should be accessible to the IDE process launched under the same user. Did you try restarting the IDE? If variables were changed, IDE terminal only picks up those changes on restart. You might even want to try rebooting your system.

In IntelliJ IDEA, configuring Java without access to environment variables can be done by setting up the JDK (Java Development Kit) manually within the IDE. This involves specifying the JDK installation path directly in IntelliJ's project settings. Additionally, IntelliJ allows for defining Java compiler options, runtime parameters, and project-specific SDK settings, all without relying on system environment variables.

Thank you for your engagement. I tried it all and it changed nothing, but i figured out that using java in git bash in my IDE works fine, so I changed to that. Somehow it seems to be a Windows Powershell specific thing (which I used before).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
